# How do I make Magit only show diff for unstaged changes?

Tags: magit, git

The default git behavior is to show only unstaged changes (ignoring stuff that I have staged/git added). How do I do that in Magit?

Comment: I can't tell whether you're asking to modify the magit status buffer, or to view the standard git diff in a separate buffer. Are you aware that if you `TAB` on the "unstaged changes" heading in the magit status buffer, it shows you the diff for those specific changes? (which you can then interact with).

Comment: And `j u` is the quick way to jump to that specific heading from *anywhere* in the status buffer, FWIW.

Answer (score 6):

Try `M-x magit-diff-unstaged`, also available in the diff popup (<kbd>d u</kbd>).

If you've globally bound `magit-dispatch-popup` to some key,then you can use that followed by <kbd>d u</kbd> to get to the unstaged diffs without having to go through the status buffer.